# Objects created via array and 'new'-operator, but how to pass parameters?

Tags: c++, constructor

Nice you're taking a look at my question, i struggle in passing parameters to objects which are created by 'new' and stored as an array. I know that with

```
Class object[2] = {Class{2, "text"},Class{5, "otherText"}}
```

it is possible without 'new'. What I want to do is like

```
pClass = new Class[2]{Class{2,"text"},Class{5,"otherText"}}
```

Some code below:

```
class AnotherClass{
  int val1;
  string str1;

public:
  //some code
};


class Class{
  AnotherClass *pToAnotherClass;
  //some more variables

public:
  Class(){ pToAnotherClass = new AnotherClass[5]};
  //some more code
};  


main{

Class object;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is your question about how to construct the AnotherClass objects in pToAnotherClass? The question isn't very clear.

Comment: Use I think you meant  `AnotherClass *pToAnotherClass ;` in that case use `std::vector<AnotherClass>`

Comment: i've rewritten the question to clarify the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally it is better to use `std::vector` instead of C style arrays for holding objects. This allows to initialize with `emplace_back`; e.g. you could then do

```
  Class()
    : v()
  {
      v.reserve(5);
      for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
      {
           v.emplace_back(val[i], str[i]);
      }
  }

  std::vector<AnotherClass> v;
```

where `val` and `str` are some arrays of values that you need to initialize the individual objects in `v`.

Comment: `vector` should also allow you to use `:v{{2, "text"},{5, "otherText"}}`